# Checking array type before unwind

Tags: mongodb, mongo-java, mongojs

I have a document with the following structure

{testfields:[{"test_id":1,"test_name":"xxxx"}]},

but , my application don't no whether "testfield" is array or plain object, now if I apply "$unwind" in aggregate query and filed is not of array type "mongodb" throws error, that cannot unwind. I wanted to know is their a way I can check if the field is of type array than apply unwind, else treat is as normal object.

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/type/#op._S_type) could help you.

Before using `unwind`, try to use a `match` to filter documents with `testfields` field is an array:

```
$match: { $where : "Array.isArray(this.testfields)" }
```

Then, you could use `unwind` without errors.

Comment: You're right. I got confused because documentation says "The $match query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax", but i didn't see last warning 'You cannot use $where in $match queries as part of the aggregation pipeline'. My apologies.

Comment: How about querying on $type 4 http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/type/ ?